# Changing style of multiple objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a website using WordPress, so the content is created dynamically.
The elements ID is also dynamically generated

Each container can have these elements (a container can have multiple - but not the same):
t_1
f_1
f_2
f_3

I also add the container count at the end of the elements ID, so each element will have a unique ID

Let's say the PHP will generate a HTML like this:

```
<div id="container_1">
  <div id=f_1_1>
    //content
  </div>
  <div id=f_2_1>
    //content
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container_2">
  <div id=t_1_2>
    //content
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container_3">
  <div id=f_1_3>
    //content
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to animate the position of these elements as the user scrolls, I added javascript to do it:

```
var scroll = window.pageYOffset;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    scroll = window.pageYOffset;
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll)
}, false)

function scroll() {
    document.getElementById("f_1_1").style.top = scroll * 10 + 'px';
}
```

So here is the problem, I don't know which elements should I get by ID.

I thought about making a loop where I check each container for the elements inside, however I think it would use too much resources and would be laggy as the function runs each time the user scrolls.


An other solution I tried is to add the javascript dynamically to each container so I know exactly which elements I need to animate. It worked only for the first container as when I added the next container there were multiple function using the same name and only the last function has been executed

```
<div id="container_1">
  <div id=f_1_1>
    //content
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll() {
      document.getElementById("f_1_"+<?php echo $pagecounter?>).style.top = scroll * 10 + 'px';
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What animation are you wanting to do? Seems to me you just want the content to always be on screen, which is the same as using position: fixed with css

Comment: You could just add a class (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) to each container and target that css class only. No fiddling with ids required.

Comment: Sorry I can't format it..
I would like all t_1 to have this:

`document.getElementById("t_1").style.top = scroll * -0.2 + 'px';'

all the f_1 to have this:

`'document.getElementById("t_1").style.top = scroll * -0.4 + 'px';'

The second container will be at the next page so

`document.getElementById("t_1").style.top = windowheight * 1 + scroll * -0.2 + 'px';'

all the f_1 to have this:

`document.getElementById("t_1").style.top = windowheight * 1 +  scroll * -0.4 + 'px';'

Comment: I am trying to figure out the CSS way, how to manage that each element is in the middle of the screen when I scroll down to its container

Answer (score 0):

You can use - [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) for animation when element is comes inside viewport.

```html
<div id="container_1">
  <div id=f_1_1 class="wow myCustomAnimation">
    //content
  </div>
  <div id=f_2_1 class="wow myCustomAnimation">
    //content
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container_2">
  <div id=t_1_2 class="wow myCustomAnimation">
    //content
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container_3">
  <div id=f_1_3 class="wow myCustomAnimation">
    //content
  </div>
</div>
```

Where you have to write `myCustomAnimation` as per your requirment.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use external library also I would like the elements to change position for each scroll movement